# How do I format a target cell based on a source cell, using VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, formatting, conditional-formatting

I'm looking to copy the format of a cell within the table [table1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9S5X.png) to cells with matching text within the second table [table2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO3qF.png).

So for instance: NOT(H) is showing as green in table 1 and I want it to show as green in cell C2 in table 2. Is there a VBA that can do this?

Comment: Can I suggest the title of the question be reworded to something more representative, such as "How do I format a target cell based on a source cell, using VBA?"

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the value of the cell `Interior.ColorIndex` property to a variable

e.g. `intCellColour = Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex`, then apply that value to the target cell

e.g. `Range("C2").Interior.ColorIndex = intCellColour`

To test this, you could add an OnClick event on the sheet to show a message box with the cell colour shown

e.g. `msgbox Selection.Interior.ColorIndex`

Be aware though, colour index only has 56 colours on the palette. You may need to move to use RGB values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a UDF like this:

```
Function CPF(src As Range, dest As Range) As Range
    Dim c As Range, fnd As Range
    For Each c In dest
        Set fnd = src.Find(c.Value, , , xlWhole)
        If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
            c.Interior.Color = fnd.Interior.Color
        End If
    Next c
    Set CPF = dest
End Function
```

Put the code in a universal module.
Then in the **Name Box** enter the following:

```
CPF(src;dest)
```

where

- *src* is the name or address of your source range (table1)
- *dest* is the name or address of your destination range (table2)

Use comma or semicolon as separator according to your local settings.
E.g.

```
CPF(B2:C4;F2:H7)
```